# inverse multiple 3x3 matrices in a big matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-compiler

I have a big matrix, 3x3x151.

I was struggling to write a code to find the inverse of each 3x3 matrix and save it in a new matrix.

tried a for loop approach but got no where

Comment: "tried a for loop approach but got no where" probably you did it wrong. Show us.

Comment: Also, inverting a matrix in acomputer is a bad idea, unless you really really know what you are doing, you will likely get bad numerical precission.

Comment: Inverting the arrays is as easy as `for i = 1:151; inv(A(:,:,i)); end`, but the real question is why you would want to do so? What is the final goal? Storing the inverse of matrices is almost always useless in practice and could even create many errors and numerical stability problems.

Answer (score 3):

This is precisely what [`pageinv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pageinv.html) was designed for. If you have R2022a or later, simply:

```
x = rand(3, 3, 151);
y = pageinv(x);
```

As the comments above point out, and as is fairly well known, the matrix inverse itself often isn't what you want. There's also [`pagemldivide`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pagemldivide.html) if that's what you really want to do.

Comment: while I acknowledge that this is a great answer to the original question, a risk factor of using these extremely new function is that your code, and whoever will need to run your code, will have to have matlab R2022a to run it. This may not be a big deal for institutes with matlab license available, it can severely limit the portability of your code, especially given an alternative implementation is not complex. For example, the `cellfun(@inv,...)` command can run on [GNU Octave](https://octave.org), which allows one to do CI/unit testing using common servers, but `pageinv()` won't allow that.

Comment: Sure. It's a potential problem whenever we introduce new stuff, but we're never going to stop adding new stuff. If it's a concern, write a wrapper and use `verLessThan` (introduced R2007a...) to guard the code. I believe `pageinv` is likely to perform significantly better than the alternatives, so it's definitely worth using when available.

Answer (score 0):

a quick solution is to split the matrix into cell arrays of 3x3 matrices, and then call `cellfun`, try this

```
a=rand(3,3,151);
b=squeeze(num2cell(a,[1,2]));
c=cellfun(@inv, b, 'UniformOutput', false)   % inversions of 3x3 matrices
```

if you want to assemble those back to a matrix, you can call

```
cmat=reshape(cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x(:), c', 'UniformOutput', false)), size(a))
```

Comment: The last step could also be done as `cmat = cat(3,c{:})`.